# Programming to multiple backends

Tags: python

My current project is a high-level abstraction package for GPIO programming on those nifty little SoC-Computers (Raspberry Pi, Cubieboard, Beaglebone Black, Pandaboard etc.). One of my goals is to make it possible to run the same code on different Boards using different GPIO modules as backends, like RPi.GPIO on the Raspberry Pi, or SUNXI_GPIO on the Cubieboard.

At the moment I have code like this:

```
class Pin(object):
    def __init__(self, gpio, direction, pud=None):
        self.gpio = gpio
        self.direction = direction
        self.pud = pud
        _GPIO_BACKEND.setuppin(self.gpio, self.direction, self.pud)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.gpio

class InputPin(Pin):
    """docstring for InputPin"""
    def read(self):
        _GPIO_BACKEND.read(self.gpio)

class OutputPin(Pin):
    """docstring for OutputPin"""
    def high(self):
        _GPIO_BACKEND.high(self.gpio)

    def low(self):
        _GPIO_BACKEND.low(self.gpio)
```

I'd like _GPIO_BACKEND to get setup by a context manager that loads the backend. The Backend itself looks like this (RPi.GPIO example):

```
from RPi import GPIO as _GPIO

def init(numberscheme='bcm'):
    """docstring for init"""
    if numberscheme.lower() == 'bcm':
        _GPIO.setup(_GPIO.BCM)
    elif numberscheme.upper() == 'board':
        _GPIO.setup(_GPIO.BOARD)

def setuppin(id, direction, pullupdown=None):
    """docstring for setuppin"""
    if direction.lower() == 'in':
        dir = _GPIO.IN
    elif direction.lower() == 'out':
        dir = _GPIO.OUT
    else:
        raise ValueError

    if pullupdown is None:
        pud = _GPIO.PUD_ # TODO
    elif pullupdown.lower() == 'up':
        pud = _GPIO.PUD_UP
    elif pullupdown.lower() == 'down':
        pud = _GPIO.PUD_DOWN
    else:
        raise ValueError

    _GPIO.setmode(id, dir, pud)

def cleanup():
    """docstring for cleanup"""
    _GPIO.cleanup()

def high(id):
    """docstring for high"""
    _GPIO.output(id, _GPIO.HIGH)

def low(id):
    """docstring for low"""
    _GPIO.output(id, _GPIO.LOW)

def read(id):
    """docstring for read"""
    return _GPIO.input(id)
```

What I don't like about this is reliance on a pseudo-invisible global variable (_GPIO_BACKEND).

What is a good, proper, and pythonic way to program towards multiple backends like this?

Comment: Is this your actual code? or hypothetical / stubbed code?

Comment: It's stubbed, but I'm just starting out with this project, so there isn't that much more to see.

Answer (score 1):

Would you not be able to handle this with classical object-oriented concepts? For example, each backend could be implemented as a class with a common interface, and InputPin and OutputPin classes would used them in a composed manner.